# Outlook for Mac SMTP failing on Google Apps

Tags: ms-office, google-apps

I have recently set up a client on Google Apps for Business. They would like to use their email via Outlook. Everything from Google Apps is perfectly synced, including folders. The client can receive emails, but they cannot send anything.

I have used these settings to configure Outlook:

Incoming Mail (IMAP) Server - Requires SSL

- imap.gmail.com
- Port: 993
- Requires SSL:Yes

Outgoing Mail (SMTP) Server - Requires TLS

- smtp.gmail.com
- Port: 465 or 587 (have tried both)
- Requires SSL: Yes
- Requires authentication: Yes
- Use same settings as incoming mail server

Full Name or Display Name: [your name]
Account Name or User Name: username@your_domain.com
Email address: username@your_domain.com
Password: password

I am receiving the following error:

> Outlook cannot find the server. Verify the server information is entered correctly in the Account Settings, and that your DNS settings in the Network pane of System Preferences are correct.

I have attached a screengrab of the Outlook configuration. You'll see that the client has 3 email accounts.

[image: Outlook configuration]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your screenshot says `stmp.gmail.com`. The correct SMTP server for gmail is `smtp.gmail.com`.

See Google's support document, [Sending mail from a printer, scanner, or app](https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en), for other configuration settings.

Comment: ROFL. That one just tripped me up too. Almost as funny as 225.255.255.0 as a subnet mask.